# Android. Как обратиться к WebView из public void onClick(View view)?

Tags: java, android

Есть конструкция которая находится в :

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ****
        ****
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ****
        ****
```

Мне необходимо обратиться к WebView из другого класса, а именно:

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
        webView.loadUrl(saitus);
```

Если обозначаю WebView в классе - public void onClick(View view), то всё работает. Но как сделать более грамотно и обращаться к webView из другого класса? Чтобы он соотвественно при этом сохранять свои настройки (webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); и др.).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам разобрался))

Объявляем

WebView webView;

Далее в onCreate за место

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Делаем

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

И всё переходит от класса к классу. Так же и сеттингами.